# Sass/Stylus convert a function iteration

Tags: sass, stylus, code-conversion

I try to pass all my workflow from Sass to Stylus, but I can not convert a function.

Here is the function in sass

```
    @mixin setIconInclude($icon) {
      @each $s in $ws_icon-list {
            @if nth($s, 1) == $icon {
                  content: nth($s, 2);
            }
      }
}
```

I tried this in Stylus but it does not work

```
setIconInclude($icon)
  for $s in $ws_icon-list
    if foo $s 0 == icon
      content foo $s 1
```

---

**Edit:**

I have a list of icons that I define in another file.

```
$ws_icon-list =       "iconName1"   "\f105",
                  "iconName2"   "\e81f",
                  "iconName3"   "\e820"
```

With the function I'm trying to achieve, I'd like to be able to access it (the SASS function works) in Stylus but I can not understand the syntax.

`$icon` is the first param of the icon I want to use as defined in the list.

Comment: Try to be more specific about "not work". Can you give a specific example input, with expected and actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$s[0]` and `$s[1]` instead of `nth($s, 1)` and `nth($s, 2)`, because Stylus lists are zero-based:

```
$ws_icon-list =   "iconName1"   "\f105",
              "iconName2"   "\e81f",
              "iconName3"   "\e820"

setIconInclude($icon)
  for $s in $ws_icon-list
    if $s[0] == $icon
      content: $s[1]

body
  setIconInclude('iconName1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got to something similar in my other tests but it did not work. With your solution, it's great! thank you very much